# How am I supposed to compile a proof to show that a function has only $1$ real zero.

Tags: calculus

For something like $$x^7 + 2x^3 + 3x - 7$$

Would I apply Rolle's theorem ?

Comment: What does this question have to do with group theory?

Comment: the example function you provided is monotonic increasing...

Comment: Yes, Rolle's theorem helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: the intermediate value theorem tells you that there is a real root for your polynomial. Then if you differentiate you get:

$$7x^6 + 6x^2 + 3$$

which is always positive.
You can easily conclude form that.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^7, x^3$ and $x$ are all strictly increasing, their sum is strictly increasing. The "$-7$" is just a translation. It follows the function is strictly increasing, therefore injective. In particular, there can be only one zero.

Observing that $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$$ and $$\lim_{x\to+ \infty} f(x) = +\infty$$ and that $f$ is continuous, there is at least one so you're done.